# Final result of nosetest does not get redirected to required file

Tags: python, nosetests

I was trying to redirect the output of nosetest to a file but I found that the final result of nosetest does not get redirected. This means that the result is not printed on stdout.So I was curious to know on which stream is the output redirected.
For example:
If I have a testcase

```
class Test(object):
    def test_1(self):
        print "\nHI"
```

~

This, when executed using nosetest will print "HI" and nosetest will print the result as:

```
src.xyz.Test.test_1 ...
HI
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s
```

But if redirected then only "HI" will be redirected to file and not the result.

Comment: redirect implying the unix redirection operator `>` ... ???

Comment: Try `2>&1` at the end of your redirection ... like `... > foo.txt 2>&1` (Not sure if it works)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for quick turn around but the question is not really how do I get the output but which stream it is redirected to.

Comment: Nosetest redirects to STDERR (I guess, Not sure ... Reason to guess - If it waas `STDOUT` then it would have gone to the file)

Comment: Yes it is stderr but didnt get the reason though why it is stderr and not stdout

Comment: Found following link about nosetest output getting redirected to stderr.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nose-dev/_29dRyC2R90

Comment: Researching more on this topic. If you find a solid answer do post the answer. Thanks :)